# Phase string to date in javascript - Chrome issue

Tags: javascript

I have a string such as '30/05/1981' in a javascript function. I am turning it into a date like this...

```
new Date(arguments.Value)
```

But in Chrome when I try to use the date I get an 'Invalid Date' error.

It works fine in all other browsers.

How would I do this in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on a browser (as clients may have different date formats).

I would advise to create a date parser or use a date library, like [datejs](http://datejs.com/) or [SugarJS](http://sugarjs.com/features)

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm using datejs now and its all good, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the date should be in format `MM/DD/YYYY`:

```
new Date("30/05/1981".replace(/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})/, "$2/$1"));
```

However `YYYY/MM/DD` should also work fine:

```
new Date("30/05/1981".split("/").reverse().join("/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This derives from the conflict of `DD/MM/YYYY` vs `MM/DD/YYYY`, which *Chrome* solves by only using the latter. You'll have to either enter dates differently or do some string matching.

```
var dateMatch = arguments.Value.match(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d\d\d)/);
new Date(+dateMatch[3], +dateMatch[2], +dateMatch[1]);
```